# Fetching analytics related to push notification in `FCM Cloud Messaging`

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to know whether push notifications are delivered to all the registrationId mapped to my user database or not.

I have 8000 users and all are having registrationId. I had sent notification to all of them and now i want to determine whether all those user had received the notification or not.

so is there any way to access this analytics using some FCM url.

I am aware that i can see analytics in google publisher from `STATISTICS` menu and selecting `FCM messages` and to check the delivery status i can go to `FCM Diagnostics`

[Firebase support page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268?hl=en)

but using that tool to determine 8k users is nearly impossible so how can i get the analytics of cloud messaging.

Long back i have seen some link but forgot to bookmark :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no API to retrieve the delivery status for sent FCM messages.

In general, when the FCM server successfully receives the payload you've sent from your App Server, it should return a `success:1` response along with a `message_id`.

If what you're aiming for is to know if the device has successfully received the message, you should implement [Delivery Receipts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/xmpp-server-ref#ccs):

> **Delivery Receipt**: If the app server included `delivery_receipt_requested` in the downstream message, the XMPP connection server sends a delivery receipt when it receives confirmation that the device received the message.