# Android push notifications analytics

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-analytics, firebase-notifications

Good afternoon! 
We’ve faced the problem when we decided to use flurry and firebase for our Android app analytics. It works well in general, except push-notification analytics. We send push notifications via firebase. They are fully automated and sent from our backend. To make things clear, the event has happened and from the backend, it goes to firebase - the title, the text, the picture, FCM user’s token. Push comes and everything’s alright.

But in Events, these pushes are not being tracked. However, Firebase has original events: notification_dismiss notification_open notification_receive

It turned out that events worked only on those pushes that were sent from FCM and it’s unbelievable! In other words: you write text manually and get the statistic but Google says: “you don’t need 90% of statistic for automated pushes”.

So my question is: What shall we do? How can we track automated pushes that are being sent from the backend? Which analytics allows to track push notifications that are being sent from FCM API?

**Shall we change analytics for push notifications?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetching analytics related to push notification in \`FCM Cloud Messaging\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42933562/fetching-analytics-related-to-push-notification-in-fcm-cloud-messaging)

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/40341195/4625829

Answer (score 0):

The automatically collected notification events (notification_dismiss notification_open notification_receive) only populate in the Analytics console when the notifications are sent via Notification console.

Push notifications sent through server are not captured as part of the automatically collected notification events.

Comment: Shall we change analytics for push notifications?